# MySQL Select only one row from second table, for each ID in first table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, row

I have two tables in relation connected with primary and foreign key.
In the **first table** I have a server list with attributes (id, name, ip,...).
In the **second table** I want to insert in future Update-Informations (id, server_id, last_update, next_update,...).

Now I want to show in my GUI the Server-Attrinbutes from first table and **only** the last entry from second table for each server with equals server_id.

Table 1:

```
id
name
ip
description
.
.
```

Table 2:

```
id
server_id
last_update
next_update
.
.
```

Here is a short example how I already tried it:

```
select s.id, s.name, sp.last_update, sp.next_update
from server s
left join (select * from server_updates order by server_id desc) sp
on sp.server_id = s.id
```

I already tried it with the statement **LIMIT 1**

```
select s.id, s.name, sp.last_update, sp.next_update
from server s
left join (select * from server_updates order by server_id desc limit 1) sp
on sp.server_id = s.id
```

Also I have tried to use **DISTINCT**

```
select DISTINCT s.id, s.name, sp.last_update, sp.next_update
from server s
left join (select * from server_updates order by server_id desc limit 1)
```

But I always got all entrys from **second table**

```
+------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+------------+
| Server0101 | Server0101_name | Server0101_ip | 2017-09-20 | 2017-10-20 |
| Server0101 | Server0101_name | Server0101_ip | 2017-10-20 | 2017-11-20 |
| Server0102 | Server0102_name | Server0102_ip | 2017-05-01 | 2017-06-01 |
```

I just want one row from second table for each ID from first table.

Of course I can implement this in my JAVA-Code, but can you please tell me how to do this in MySQL.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below one?

```
select s.id, s.name, sp.last_update, sp.next_update
from server s
left join (select * from server_updates where server_id =s.id order by server_id desc limit 1) sp
on sp.server_id = s.id
```

Comment: Hi Nidhi257, thanks for the fast response. I tried it right now but I got the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 's.id' in 'where clause'.